# Shell scripting: extracting absolute path from default value of path variable

Tags: shell, scripting, zsh

I am writing a shell script that takes argument $1 as a destination directory and $2 as a source directory.
Script:

```
#!/bin/zsh
# readlink is used to get absolute path when relative path is provided
output_path=`readlink -f "${1:-.}"`
src_dir=`readlink -f -- "${2:-~/Downloads}"`
echo "destination dir: $output_path"
echo "source dir: $src_dir"
return
```

Output:

```
destination dir: /home/ashwin
source dir:
```

I get blank in source directory variable.
Changing the default value of `src_dir` to the absolute path of folder solves the problem.
Script:

```
#!/bin/zsh
# readlink is used to get absolute path when relative path is provided
output_path=`readlink -f "${1:-.}"`
src_dir=`readlink -f -- "${2:-/home/ashwin/Downloads}"`
echo "destination dir: $output_path"
echo "source dir: $src_dir"
return
```

Output:

```
destination dir: /home/ashwin
source dir: /home/ashwin/Downloads
```

Also providing `~/Downloads` as an argument to script works fine.
I want to understand the reason why `~/Downloads` as the default value of `src_dir` does not work.

Comment: `~` doesn't ever work in quotes. Use `$HOME` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to understand the reason why ~/Downloads as the default value of src_dir does not work.

From [bash manual tilde expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Tilde-Expansion):

> If a word begins with an unquoted tilde character (‘~’), ...

The `"${2:-~/Downloads}"` doesn't begin with an unquoted tilde character. And the result `~/Downloads` is quoted within double `"`. The `~` is not expanded. So `readlink -f -- "~/Downloads"` is run. Because the path named literally `/home/ashwin/~/Downloads` doesn't exists on your system, `readlink` generates no output and exits with a nonzero exit status (1 on my system).

Please do not use backticks `. Use `$(  )` instead.

Comment: `Please do not use backticks. Use $(  ) instead.`
Is this related to ~ expansion or a general observation?
Can you please explain why $( ) is preferable to `?

Comment: General [bash hackers wiki deprecated and obsolete syntax](https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete).